# Range contains element filter not using index of the element column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a timestamp column that has a btree index.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tstest AS
SELECT '2019-11-10'::timestamp + random() * '10 day'::interval ts
FROM generate_series(1,10000) s;

CREATE INDEX ON tstest(ts);
```

I would like to find all row between a timerange. Both ends of the range can be "infinite"/null, start of the range must be exclusive and end is inclusice. So this forms a query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tstest WHERE ts <@ tsrange($1, $2, '(]');
```

The result is correct but the index of the ts column is not used and a seq scan is done instead.

To use the index correctly I have to do the query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tstest WHERE  ($1 IS null OR $1 < ts) AND ($2 IS null OR ts <= $2);
```

I like the <@ syntax more. It is easier to understand and it is shorter.
Is there something I can do differently to utilize the index and make the query faster? Maybe a different type of index instead?

I have also tried to add a gist index for ts column using the [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) module but that didn't change the situation.

I have tested this with PostgreSQL 9.6 and 12.0.

Answer (score 0):

A btree index (which you are using) doesn't support the `<@` operator and a GiST index wouldn't help because the timestamp column isn't a range type.

But you can still make the btree index usable by using coalesce and `infinity` which removes the use of the `OR` condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tstest 
WHERE ts > coalesce($1, '-infinity') 
  and ts <= coalesce($2, 'infinity');
```